# How to use prepared statements with Enterprise Library?

Tags: c#, enterprise-library

Is there a way to tell Enterprise Library to use prepared statements?  If so, how?

Comment: By prepared statements, do you mean parameterized sql statements?

Comment: No, I do mean prepared statements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is to use DbCommand.Prepare();

The long answer is that it is completely irrelevant, and results in a noop, when calling stored procedures.

Also, it should only really be used when the code is about to make several calls (as in a loop) with the same query.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to obtain the sqlConnection / Command being executed -> can't you set the relevant setting here before executing ??

Hope I've got the right end of the stick...